# IE Developer tool says my body tag is empty on a responsive site in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I just wrapped up this responsive site and now it doesn't appear in IE9. Somewhere along the way I've done something that messed it up.

Site at http://www.dermatologypartners.com and it looks great in modern browsers, decent in IE8 and invisible in IE9. Also good on iPads, iphones, etc.

I did a desktop first oriented stylesheet so that IE8 would show up even though I'm using media queries for the tablet and phone versions.

I've got the html5 shiv in my header, and some code to make gradients work in IE9.

I don't know what to do now - Help!!

Comment: I figure out that I had an error in a script - fixed that and site appeared! Had left off a line when cutting and pasting - basic stupid mistake. Ah well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an error in a script - missing a closing. Fixed that and the site now appears in ie9. Other problems to resolve but that one is solved.

Read an article that advised looking for little script errors

Answer (score 3):

i faced the problem that an space before an closing xml comment , led the browser treating the comment as not closed, so he simply ignored the rest of the page

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif] -->
```

in this case, it was the space after `[endif]`